# Python Hangman: Trouble assigning game word using returned value from function

Tags: python

In this case, I'm selecting a random word from the word_list to use as the game_word. The problem is, as this value is returned in the local scope of the get_random_word() function, it's not being saved after it's called in the main() function.

I've come across advice saying I need to pass in some sort of argument (which the code posted below currently does not do). I'm not quite sure how to implement this.

I've been told expicitly that I'm not to use "global" in the get_random_word() function.

```
import random

word_list = ['apple', 'berry', 'cherry', 'arkansas', 'mississippi', 'hawaii', 'serendipity', 'insomnia']

def get_random_word():

    random_word = random.choice(word_list)
    return random_word

def replace_blanks_with_correct_letter(current_output, guess):

    for (index, letter) in enumerate(game_word):
        if letter == guess:
            current_output[index] = letter
    print ''.join(current_output)


def main():

    # Herein lies the problem...
    game_word = get_random_word()

    current_output = len(game_word) * ['_']

    while True:

        replace_blanks_with_correct_letter(current_output, have_player_guess_letter())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please when asking questions try to create an [mcve]. I've removed most of what appeared to not be part of the actual question but feel free to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42549958/edit) or roll back anything you think that was needed

Comment: I think you removed too much

Comment: @abccd - You can look at the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42549958/revisions) and see that everything I removed was just commentary or just code that was documented to say it works ok, hence not part of the issue. The OP is welcome to rollback any changes

Comment: `replace_blanks_with_correct_letter` was actually a part of the problem, the OP thought it was not...

Comment: thank you for rolling it back

Comment: I edited the code I posted to remove all unnecessary comments in there. Thanks for letting me know. First time posting, so I'm learning what proper custom to post here is. I did include the code I felt necessary, as the issue I was encountering cropped up when running it (the error was thrown after the first input of a guess).

Answer (score 0):

You can move `word_list` definition to `main` function, and pass it like this:

```
def get_random_word(word_list):

    random_word = random.choice(word_list)
    return random_word

def main():

    word_list = ['apple', 'berry', 'cherry', 'arkansas', 'mississippi', 'hawaii', 'serendipity', 'insomnia']
    game_word = get_random_word(word_list)
```

You can also consider reading words from file if it's allowed.

Comment: Reading from a file is going to be something I add further down the line once the game functionality is all in place. I did end up going with the poster's suggestion, as that seems to be the best option for the time being. But I thank you greatly for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that your game_word is local in `main()` Here's a way to fix this without using `global`:

```
import random

# For finished game, import .txt file(s) for word choice
word_list = ['apple', 'berry', 'cherry', 'arkansas', 'mississippi', 'hawaii', 'serendipity', 'insomnia']    # sample list--good for testing

def get_random_word():

    random_word = random.choice(word_list)
    return random_word


def have_player_guess_letter():

    player_guess = raw_input('Guess a letter: ')
    return player_guess


def replace_blanks_with_correct_letter(current_output, guess, game_word): #add game_word as an argument

    for (index, letter) in enumerate(game_word):
        if letter == guess:
            current_output[index] = letter
    print ''.join(current_output)


def main():

    game_word = get_random_word()

    current_output = len(game_word) * ['_']

    while True:

        replace_blanks_with_correct_letter(current_output, have_player_guess_letter(), game_word) #call game_word as an argument


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

or you can also put `game_word = get_random_word()` here:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    game_word = get_random_word()
    main()
```

Comment: Brilliant. I went with the first option, and it works beautifully. I was positive I needed to add some sort of parameter, I just wasn't sure where it needed to be, and you've cleared that up for me. Thank you so much, greatly appreciated!